# How do you go about texture painting models with LODs?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm trying to texture paint some models with LODs. These will be game assets so I also have to atlas them. Should I atlas all LOD_0s and then match UVs of the rest of LODs to this texture paint or do I have to make a texture for every set of LODs separately?

Answer (score 1):

Separate textures are not required. Textures typically use [mip-mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap), which generates all necessary texture sizes. Adding textures doubles this information.